# Comparing an undefined string and undefined type

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a program and ran into a situation where I wanted to short circuit a statement if a variables data type was undefined. I compared `typeof(var)` to the keyword undefined which in all situations returned false.

`console.log(undefined == "undefined"); //false`

Due to type coercion shouldn't these be considered the same thing? What am I missing here?

Comment: `"undefined"` is a string, and thus truthy. `undefined` is falsy. The result is exactly the same as `undefined == "some text"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with types, you need to use `typeof(undefined)`.

```
typeof(undefined) == "undefined" // true
undefined == "undefined" // false
```

Here is a working example.

```js
document.getElementById("test1").value = typeof(undefined) == "undefined";
document.getElementById("test2").value = undefined == "undefined";
```

```html
typeof(undefined) == "undefined"
<br/>
<input id="test1"/>
<br/>
undefined == "undefined"
<br/>
<input id="test2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
("undefined" === typeof variable) //True
```

typeof is going to return a string.